# NFC Vcard the tag not supported by iOS

Tags: ios, nfc, vcf-vcard, ndef

I have a Mifare Classic NFC card, I used NFC Tools to add a vcard to it, it works very well with Android, but when I go to use with iOS it refuses to work, the error is the tag not supported by iOS.

for reference :
[www.v1ce.co](http://www.v1ce.co)

Answer (score 0):

While iOS supports reading/writing at the low level to the non NFC standard Mifare Classic cards I don't believe it supports the non standard encoding needed to store Ndef Records on Mifare Classic Tags. (not tested)

If you looks at the [sample App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app?language=objc) it says

> how to use Core NFC in an app to read Near Field Communication (NFC) tags of types 1 through 5 that contains NFC Data Exchange Format (NDEF) data

As Mifare Classic Tags are not Type 1,2,3,4 or 5 Tags I don't think iOS natively supports reading Ndef data from them, you would have to write your own App to implement the proprietary encoding of Ndef [AN1305](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1305.pdf)

On Android the implementation of Mifare Classic support and AN1305 is optional, some phones support it some don't (so you phone might support it but others won't)

So instead of having to write you own implementation of AN1305 for iOS and some Android devices in an App it would be much better for you to use a NFC Forum Standards compliant Tag instead of the non standard Mifare Classic.

The NTAG 21x series of Tags are Standard Type2 Tags and should be natively supported on all iOS and Android Devices and thus they should both handle the Ndef Vcard data without and App.